# incompatible pointer types

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, youtube, xcode4.2

In this subclass of UIWebView, I am looking to set up a method to create an embedded youtube video. However, no matter how I edit this code (which I found most of online), it is always giving me a warning at the line:

```
self = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

Im not sure whether this is because of Xcode 4.2 or iOS 5 or the fact that I am using self. Is there actually something wrong? If so, how might I fix it?

Entire method code:

```
- (videosView *)initWithStringAsURL:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame;
{
    if (self = [super init]) 
    {
        // Create webview with requested frame size
        self = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        // HTML to embed YouTube video
        NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<html><head>\
        <body style=\"margin:0\">\
        <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
        width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
        </body></html>"; 

        // Populate HTML with the URL and requested frame size
        NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeVideoHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];



        // Load the html into the webview
        [self loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    }
    return self;  
}
```

Comment: I hope you read my answer too.  It addresses the nature of your warning.  "You are getting a complaint about incompatible pointer types because ..."  Kevin's answer is informative towards another mistake you make (allocating inside of the init method) and solved your problem as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the memory allocated (pointed to by `this`), so don't `alloc` more:

```
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
```

And, looking a bit more, you shouldn't `init` super twice.  Move that statement into the `if`, instead of the plain `super init`:

```
if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {...}
```

Comment: in regards to the second part of your answer, would i still keep the `self = [super initWithFrame:frame];` in the {...}? along with in the if statement

Comment: No, take that one out.  Just initialize `super` once, in the `if` statement (or just before, like in Maudicus's answer).

Answer (score 0):

In your context, self refers to an instance of your class (call MyWebView : UIWebView)

From outside your class, I hope you are creating an instance like so

```
MyWebView *myInstance = [[MyWebView alloc] initWithStringAsURL:urlString frame:frame]; // release at a later time
```

In your init method

```
- (videosView *)initWithStringAsURL:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame;
```

You can initialize by referring to super

```
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self != nil) {
// proceed with custom initialization
}
```

You are getting a complaint about incompatible pointer types because

```
[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

returns a UIWebView, not a MyWebView